# SSIS Download and Upload file from sharepoint online folder

Tags: sharepoint, service, ssis, integration

I need to download all files in a directory from sharepoint online. I've found many c# script on web but no ones download all files in a directory. Once I've downloaded the files I need to process them using SSIS and then I need to upload other files to sharepoint

I've found many c# script on web but no ones download all files in a directory